# Releasing a multi-module Maven project hosted in single Git repository

Tags: git, maven, maven-release-plugin, multi-module

I'm trying to release individual modules of a multi-module project, contained within a single git repository.

The folder structure looks something like this:

```
  |- api/pom.xml
  |- database/pom.xml
  |- core/pom.xml
  pom.xml
```

The parent pom is simply used as a way of building all subcomponents in a way that makes sense by the use of the `<modules>` tag. In essence, building api, then database, then core.

The project started out hosted in SVN and by simply pointing to different paths in the repository in the maven `scm` tag it was easy to get the `maven release` commands to play nice. This doesn't seem to be the case with Git.

When running `mvn release:prepare` it performs changes on the api pom as desired, but when performing `mvn release:perform` it attempts to build the parent pom, and fails to build the database package due to it's inability to resolve the api-snapshot dependency that is listed in database/pom.xml.

How should I configure my scm tags to be able to release a specific module within the Git repository? Is this even possible?

#### Edit: adding pom samples

Here's an example setup of how the pom files look:

**parent pom.xml**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.findwise.hydra</groupId>
  <artifactId>hydra-parent</artifactId>
  <version>0.2.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>api</module>
    <module>database</module>
    <module>core</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

**api/pom.xml**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.findwise.hydra</groupId>
  <artifactId>hydra-api</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>0.2.0</version>
  <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
  <description>Hydra API</description>

  <licenses>
    ...
  </licenses>

  <scm>
    ...
  </scm>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    ...
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
    <plugins>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

The `database` pom looks very much like `api`, but has a dependency to `api`. The same goes for `core`, which depends on `database` (and through it, on `api`).

The `api` and `database` artifacts themselves are important on their own though, as `api` defines the client API and `database` the backend API, both of which are used for integrating with the application. From this stems the original thought of releasing them separately -- the parent pom is merely an afterthought to allow simpler building of the entire stack.

Comment: Are you using parent tags in your api, database or core module to reference things from you parent pom ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The usual way to release a multi-module build is to do it from the root position which means also to release all it's sub modules with it. Not releasing a single module separately. If you try to do so you will loose the relationship of the versions to each other.

If you really want to release the modules separately just make separate maven projects out of it and give them each a git repository.

The tree you mentioned looks really like a multi module build which should be released in a single step from the root.

Based on what you have updated i can recommend that you should go with a real multi-module build with a structure like the following:

```
root
 +-- pom.xml (1.0-SNAPSHOT)
 !
 +-- api 
 !     +-- pom.xml (1.0-SNAPSHOT)
 +-- database
 !     +-- pom.xml (1.0-SNAPSHOT)
 +-- core
       +-- pom.xml (1.0-SNAPSHOT)
```

The best is to use inheritance in Maven which means to use in every module api, core, database a parent like this:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.findwise.hydra</groupId>
    <artifactId>hydra-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>hydra-api</artifactId>

  <description>Hydra API</description>
```

This give you the option to put everything which is common in api, core and database into the parent. For example you should put the license information only into the parent, the properties like them:

```xml
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
```

and furthermore you can put information [about plugins](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management) you are using into the parent as well like:

```xml
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
```

and of course you have to define the scm area only a single time in the parent and many other things as well.

Also it's possible and recommended to define [dependencyManagement](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependency_Management) into the parent which gives you the chance to define the dependencies only at one point with their appropriate versions and no need to define the version in the modules.

This will result in dramatically reducing the size of the pom's in the modules.

The result will be to release from the parent via a single `mvn release:prepare` etc. but will produce different artifacts like `hydra-api`, `hydra-core` and `hydra-database` having the same version number which will make sure to have the *api*, *core* etc. in accordance with each other.

Comment: I'm not using parent tags in the module pom.xml. The "parent" pom in the root directory more or less only exists to allow building core and all the other components in the right order. Do I need to use the parent tag in the "child module" POMs? And would a one-step release of the parent release all module artifacts, or just some sort of super artifact?

Comment: If you use it to build in the correct order you have dependencies from e.g. core to api etc. In this case i would recommend to make a real multi-module build and release from a single point as i described. Can you post your parent pom and maybe a module as well? Makes discussion simpler.

Comment: Added some more information regarding the poms. Thanks for any suggestions you might have! :)

Comment: Excellent suggestions. Thank you! I ended up releasing manually this time, but will rearrange the pom's as you suggest - looks like the correct and best way to do it.